# Why each fields is displaying values thrice instead of one time in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following tables:

- TB1: `Student` (StudentID (pk), FirstName, LastName)
- TB2: `ContactType` (ContactTypeId (pk), Contact_Type)
- TB3: `Contact` (ContactId (pk), StudentID (fk), ContactInfo, ContactDate, ContactTypeId (fk))

I have inserted 3 values into `Contact_Type`

```
1    mail
2    email
3    phone
```

and 10 values in `Student` table. I am trying to accomplish a task such that if the `Studentid` is 2 and `ContactTypeID` is 1, then on using join statement it should only display `Studentid` and should display only mail. When I try to run below JOIN statement it is displaying all 3 columns after executing below join statement.

Student table:

```
INSERT INTO Student(FirstName,LastName)
VALUES ('Franklin', 'Babb'), ('Frederick', 'Raub'), ('William', 'Liess'),
       ('Thomas', 'Santiago'), ('Marian', 'Draudit'),('Aurther', 'Harrington'),
       ('William', 'Sanson'), ('Bobby', 'McLain'), ('Noble', 'Hughes'),
       ('Edwin', 'Hart')
```

`ContactType` table has the following info:

```
  INSERT INTO ContactType(Contact_Type)
  VALUES ('Email'), ('Phone'), ('Mail')
```

`Contact` table has the following info.

```
INSERT INTO Contact(StudentID, ContactTypeId, ContactInfo, ContactDate)
VALUES (1, 2, 'N/A', '1 Oct 2017'),
       (2, 1, 'Student was contacted via email and phone', '5 Oct 2017'),
       (3, 3, 'N/A', '15 Oct 2017'),
       (4, 1, 'N/A', '25 Oct 2017'),
       (5, 3, 'Student was contacted via email and mail', '15 Nov 2017'),
       (6, 2, 'Student was contacted via email and phone', '15 Oct 2017'),
       (7, 3, 'Student was contacted via mail and phone', '10 Oct 2017'),
       (8, 3, 'Student was contacted via email and phone', '2 Oct 2017'),
       (9, 2, 'Student was contacted via email and phone', '5 Oct 2017'),
       (10, 2, 'N/A', '23 Oct 2017')
```

JOIN statement:

```
SELECT
    Student.StudentID,
    ContactType.Contact_Type,
    Student.LastName + ',' + FirstName AS Student_Name,
    Contact.ContactInfo, Contact.ContactDate
FROM 
    Student
JOIN 
    Contact ON Student.StudentID = Contact.StudentID
JOIN 
    ContactType ON Student.StudentID = Contact.StudentID
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Sami. I tried LEFT JOIN still no luck                                                           SELECT
Student.StudentID
,ContactType.Contact_Type
,Student.LastName+','+FirstName AS Student_Name
,Contact.ContactInfo
,Contact.ContactDate
FROM Student
LEFT JOIN Contact ON Student.StudentID=Contact.StudentID
LEFT JOIN ContactType ON Student.StudentID=Contact.StudentID

Comment: @Sami. Added required info.

Comment: Upvoted for using the word thrice

Comment: Your second `ON` is repeating the join. Your second `ON` should instead be defining the join between `Contact` and `ContactType`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid. Yes you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `JOIN ON` condition for both joined tables, the conditions should be different, like this:

```
SELECT
...
FROM Student
JOIN Contact     ON Student.StudentID         = Contact.StudentID
JOIN ContactType ON ContactType.ContactTypeID = Contact.ContactTypeID
```

Comment: Use `Aliases` please.

Comment: @Peter B the code worked now. Thanks! I was curious what if I would have used LEFT JOIN

Comment: With `LEFT JOIN` all Student records will be returned, and the Contact fields in the same output row will be NULL if no matching Contact record can be found. The same goes then for ContactType.